# Shortcut to new task from report tab

Tags: reporting, custom-button

I need a shortcut to create new tasks from the Report page.
This tab does not show the sidebar so I need some other solution e.g. button or link.
What are my options?
Can I add a button to this page?

Answer (score 6):

About the best that you could do would be to create a formula field on the object for which you are reporting, and have that field included on the report details. Formula might look like this:

```
HYPERLINK("/00T/e","New Task")
```